# loop start quicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like this function to begin quicker once it ends. Thanks.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/5/

Here is an actual timing I am currently using: http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/51/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 1, dir = 1, curFx = 'fadeIn';
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (i == 6 && $('#slide1').is(':visible')) {
        $('#slide1').fadeOut(2000);             
        return;
    }

    $('#slide'+ i)[curFx](500);

    i = i + 1*dir;

    if (i == 10 || i == -1) {
        dir = (dir == 1)?-1:1;
        curFx = (curFx == 'fadeIn')?'fadeOut':'fadeIn';
    }        
}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Have you even attempted to look up the `setTimeout()` function?

Comment: Tom, I would appreciate your help if know how. Thanks

Comment: Instead of using `setInterval` to run the function repeatedly at a fixed interval, you need to use `setTimeout` at the end of each run to schedule the next run. Then you can change the timing depending on `i`.

Comment: Ok emailing me telling me I should help you wasn't necessary. You mentioned you don't know how to program, then you need to hire a programmer to fix your problem. You'll also no doubt get help from other people on the site as time passes.

Comment: Tom, you need to grow some generosity and humbleness. If I was a programmer, I would not be asking you this. This place is to get help from programmers and learning from samples.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `500` at the end. It is the number of milliseconds between each executions of the script. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/49/

Comment: Mooseman, that would speed up the rest of the animation. I just want to reduce the delay in the end-pause-beginning.